# How to configure successHandler correctly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating a custom Authentication filter that overrides `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. Here are relevant portions of my config

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAt(customAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)....

}
     @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(Arrays.asList(
                new ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy(),
                new CsrfAuthenticationStrategy(csrfTokenRepository())
        ));
    }
    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(actService.actuatorService());
        authenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
        authenticationFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
        authenticationFilter.setPasswordParameter("password");
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler());
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        authenticationFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
        return authenticationFilter;
    }
```

And here's relevant portions of `CustomAuthenticationFilter`.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
....
  @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        Authentication res = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
        if (actuator.processRequest(request)) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("Actuator", true);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Without the snippet below I get an error popup saying - `TypeError: failed to fetch`  Comparing this snippet with the code in the parent(`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication`), it looks like the only difference is the additional callout there to `successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authResult);`

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Am I configuring my success handler incorrectly?